# SSAS Security Role Not Working on PowerBI Reports

Tags: sql-server, ssas, powerbi, ssas-2012

I have created a security role in SSAS which will enable the user1 to see data for USA country only. I have created a report in PowerBI desktop and published it on the PBI site. But when user1 opens the same report in PowerBI, it can see data for all countries including USA. Can anyone tell me how SSAS security roles work on the reports created on the same SSAS cube in PowerBI site.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would check two things.

1. Can you confirm the security works in SSAS? Connect with SSMS and browse as a member of the USA only role.
2. Confirm that the Power BI report is using a live connection to SSAS rather than importing the data from SSAS.

PowerBI.com connects to your SSAS DB with an admin account and passes the user context through the On Premises Gateway via the EffectiveUserName connection property. The email address (used to log into Power BI) that is passed into EffectiveUserName has to match a UPN property on an Active Directory account. Power BI does offer mapping of users to UPNs.

Guy In a Cube has a great blog post with videos on this topic [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-gateway-enterprise-manage-ssas/#map-user-names).